# Mongoose: using the Model.create() method and new Model() constructor seem to ignore parameters

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-models

I am trying to save a new document to a collection, but rather than taking the parameters from the Model() constructor or Model.create() method, an empty object is created.
I am probably doing something wrong or missing a small detail somewhere but I am currently stuck. My mongoDB database is hosted locally on mongodb for windows.

I have a schema and model:

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const CardSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    sideA: String,
    sideB: String,
}) 

export const CardSetSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user_email: String,
    name: String,
    cards: [CardSchema],
});

const CardSet = mongoose.model('CardSet', CardSchema);

export default CardSet
```

I have an endpoint trying to make a new document:

```js
    .post(async (req, res) => {
        const obj = { user_email: req.user_email, name: req.body.name, cards: [] };
        const cardSet = new CardSet(obj);
        await cardSet.save();
        res.status(201).json(cardSet);
    })
```

When looking at the data with console.log the object and cardSet look the following:

```
{ user_email: 'example-email@gmail.com', name: 'wa', cards: [] }
{ _id: new ObjectId("62481f4964d4b1789c3110c3") }
```

My connection URL looks like this:
`mongodb://localhost:27017/flash-card-test`

When I check MongoDB Compass the collection is indeed being populated with empty objects.

Does anyone have any idea what could be going wrong here? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It was a mistake. I built a model from the CardSchema rather than the CardSet schema.

Comment: Don't be too harsh on yourself haha, at least your question was well structured